# Is storing in $_SERVER accessible to everyone in YII?

Tags: php, yii

Let's say I have 4 users logged in from 4 different machines. The site is about auctions. Each auction's date remains static. Can I do something like this:

```
$_SERVER['auctions'][0]['name'] = 'Auction 1';
```

And then if any of the 4 users log in, and there is this piece of code:

```
print $_SERVER['auctions'][0]['name'];
```

All 4 will see the same result? In other words, is this some kind of global memory that I can use to cache stuff that doesn't change frequently? Or is there better ways to do this?

Comment: Why don't you store this data in a database rather than using superglobals?

Comment: No it isn't; and it isn't persistent either.... it'll be lost for all subsequent requests even by the same user.... if you want global memory, the userdata can be stored in APC

Comment: Also, do you mean $_SESSION and not $_SERVER?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $_SERVER variable is used by PHP to return information about the your webserver and server based information, it is not a place to store data.  The contents of $_SERVER are generated every time a script runs and nothing can be stored there and retrieved in another instance of a script.

You can use something like [memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) to store common data.  memcached works as a form of shared memory/cache and is easy to install and use. You could also build an array and serialize to a file and reload it like json_encode => file_put_contents to save and file_get_contents => json_decode to retrieve it.   Avoid sessions because they are per user and wouldn't suit your requirement of sharing between multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should store your auctions in a database.

Storing data in sessions is only an option for several users if they will have the same session identifier in cookies. But this can cause some serious security issues.

`$_SERVER` array seems to refresh completely each time you reload a page.